# Как отличить две строки, одна из которых содержит вторую в сообщении

Tags: java, строки, telegram-bot

У меня задача - триггербот для телеграма. То есть бот должен найти в сообщении слово-триггер и отправить сообщение в ответ. Но вот незадача - иногда один триггер может содержать в себе второй. Например:

триггер - ответ1
большойтриггер - ответ2

Я ищу триггер в сообщении так:

```
List<String> triggersList = getTriggers(chatId);
    for (String s : triggersList) {
        if (text.toLowerCase().contains(s)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Если в сообщении обнаружится "триггер" то бот отправит "ответ1".

Но если в сообщении будет "большойтриггер" бот все равно обнаружит "триггер" и отправит "ответ1". А надо чтобы бот отправил "ответ2".

Есть способы решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отсортируйте массив триггеров по длине, таким образом вы всегда будете брать наибольший возможный

Comment: Не подскажете как это сделать?

Comment: Может есть более изящное решение, но
`triggersList.sort()
 triggersList.reverse()`

Сортировка по возрастанию и разворот массива. Это позволит избегать обработки малых триггеров первыми

Answer (score 0):

А зачем ты boolean-проверку делаешь? Можно проверять не факт наличия определенного набора символов в сообщении, а просто делать сравнение - если определённый набор символов есть в заданной строке (в д.сл. в тексте сообщения), то отправляй/распечатывай само сообщение, а не проверочное слово-сигнал (хотя они могут и полностью совпасть, тогда тоже подойдёт).
Предположим нам пришло несколько сообщений. Для упрощения я поместил их в String массив, а не список, но это не важно - по итератору можно обойти и то, и другое. У нас есть проверочное слово "trigger". Обходим массив сообщений и, если в сообщении есть заданное слово, распечатывем (или отправляем и т.д.) само сообщение, а не проверочное слово.

```
    public class Example{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            // массив сообщений
            String[] massiv = {"trooper", "trigger", "anything", "bigtrigger"};            
            // проверочное слово
            String s = "trigger";           
            /* 
               вызываем метод обхода и проверки массива,
               в параметры передаем массив сообщений и
               проверочное слово
            */ 
            check(massiv, s);
        }
        /*  
            метод проверки массива сообщений на наличие
            проверочного слова "trigger", при обнаружении 
            распечатывем тест сообщения иначе - игнорируем.
        */
        public static void check(String[] m, String str){
            for(String text: m){
                if(text.toLowerCase().contains(str)){
                    System.out.println(text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Вывод программы:

trigger

bigtrigger

Остальные слова (сообщения) не распечатаются/отправятся.